# Display Image using object (Iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Here is what I have:

```
 smallURL:(@"bundle://image.jpg")
```

this line will display me a picture store in the local path, no problem everything works fine. Now I'm using an object because the name for my picture will be store in my database, so I want to use the line like that:

```
 smallURL:(@"bundle://%s", [visuel lpath])
```

My problem is "%s" its not working do I have to use %@, %i... can someone help me and explain all the diference..

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  smallURL:([NSString stringWithFormat:@"bundle://%@", [visuel lpath]])
```

Comment: Thanks its working now, but why do I have to pecify NSString again? I don't understand.

Comment: NSLog is special. It supports recieving both a string with a format and its parameters. smallURL only takes one parameter, a string. In order for the single parameter to smallURL to be correctly formatted we have to first create a new string with a format and then pass the resulting foratted string to smallURL.

Answer (score 1):

If `lpath` is of type `NSString` then you should use `%@`. It is used every time you need to convert a Cocoa object (or any other descendant of `NSObject`) into its string representation.

```
smallURL:(@"bundle://%@", [visuel lpath])
```

Comment: It seems to work, thanks. Now I have another problem and I don't know why, when I use what you told me the picture don't want to display and if I use NSLog(@"bundle://%@", [visuel lpath]); the path for the picture is good --> bundle://image.jpg

Comment: I beleive that Niels Castle has already answered that question in his comment to the Hoang's answer. The right decisiion is to use the syntax suggested by Hoang.